# is embedded list comprehension in python possible?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

So I am trying to wrap my head around list comprehension. Here is what I have.

```
all_students = [line.split() for line in data]
all_students = [[data.strip() for data in student]for student in all_students]
```

Works great. Returns my array of arrays as expected. My question is, is it possible to combine both these expressions into one? I have tried many things and the answer (if it is possible) has still eluded me.

Comment: while it's nice to play with nested list comprehension, if you exaggerate it becomes unreadable and harder to maintain and debug. Leave it as it is - my two cents.

Comment: Could you provide an example structure for `data`?

Comment: `list(map(str.strip, map(str.split, data)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your logic is equivalent to this one:

```
[[d.strip() for d in line.split()] for line in data]
```

An example(not exactly sure if it is your case):

```
data = ['a b', 'c d']

[[d.strip() for d in line.split()] for line in data]
# [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]

all_students = [line.split() for line in data]
[[data.strip() for data in student]for student in all_students]
# [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
```

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Now that I see it, it seems obvious. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this?

```
all_students = [[d.strip() for d in stu] for stu in map(str.split, data)]
```

Comment: Why not map `str.strip` also?

Comment: Yeah, that works, but I never like to use `map`, except it makes the code more readable. Plus using an outer `map` would require a call to `list` for Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can put another list comprehension in place of `all_students`:

```
all_students = [[data.strip() for data in student] for student in [line.split() for line in data]]
```